# Query a SPList with managed metadata column with CAML including child terms

Tags: 2013, caml, taxonomy, application-pages

I have a SharePoint list which has a managed metadata column. This is bound to my term store which look like as following:

- Cars

  - Mercedes

    - S600
    - CL65
    - G
  - BMW

    - 5
    - 6
    - 7
    - X5
  - Maybach

    - ...
  - Bentley

I want to query via CAML this list. I have a custom application page where the user is able to select the terms from the term store by drop downs. Given is a ListItem where the user has selected the term "S600" from the parent term "Mercedes". Lets think that the user now only selects "Mercedes".

How can I query the list with CAML so that I also get all items which where tagged with the children of the term "Mercedes"?

In short: How can I build a CAML query which can get all items with the selected parent terms child terms?

Comment: Has noone an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The magic words are [TaxonomyField.GetWssIdsOfTerm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.taxonomy.taxonomyfield.getwssidsofterm.aspx).

This question is a dupicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258722/how-does-one-get-all-child-terms-of-a-sharepoint-term-in-c.